# Provider error: transaction would cause overdraft: I got this error when deploying to sepolia testnet

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, python, rust

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config();
const { ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL, WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

console.log(ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL);


module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      chainId: 11155111,
      url: ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY]

    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the time when your wallet has low funds, meaning that the transaction fees will cause your wallet balance to go below 0. Make sure to fund your wallet before deploying.

Let me know if this is the case, or else there can be another reason with providers, try different providers to make sure.

Comment: I will try it out and reach out to you.